# Multiple Word answers to prompts in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Currently I am creating a chat bot, but everything goes fine if I want to create a one word question or word. For example:

```
set /p chat=You:
if %chat%==hello echo User: Hello!
```

But if I try:

```
if %chat%==who are you? echo User: My name is Stacy.
```

The `.bat` file crashes. I am very new to this coding language so could I just get an explanation of what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Because I am actually making a CMD prompt game that is looking really good so far and this bot is vital.

Comment: `if "%chat%"=="who are you?"`, or even better, `if /I "%chat%"=="who are you?"` (case-insensitive comparison)... The batch files does not "crash", it returns a syntax error, which you will not see when you run it by double-clicking on it...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So how would I make it so it tells me the errors instead of instantly closing the window?

Comment: Open a command prompt and run the script by typing its name instead of double-clicking the script.

Comment: Open a command prompt window (_Win+R_, type `cmd`, _OK_), type `cd /D` followed by a _space_ followed by the quoted path where your batch file is stored, press _return_, then type the quoted name of the batch file and press _return_ again...

Comment: ALSO! The solution you have given me doesn't work. The window still immediatly closes after I type "who are you?" without quotes. And yes I have an outcome so I know its broken still in case you're wondering.

Comment: It works, unless you enter something that contains `"`...

Comment: Ill just put the entire ChatBot method in. :ChatBot
echo CLIENT CONNECTED. Say Hello.
set /p chat=You:
if %chat%==hello echo User: Hello.. Anything you need while I can talk? These chats are on a timer.
if /I "%chat%"=="who are you?" echo User: My name is stacy. Im a Help assistant here at USFIB.
goto ChatBot

Answer (score 0):

(answer based on your comments above)

aschipfl had it right.

You had an instance where `%chat%` was not quoted, therefore it's as if you were trying to run `if /i who are you==hello ...` which was causing the problem. It was expecting an operator after who, but it got `are`.

Follow this template: `if /i "%chat%"=="blah blah" echo ...`

Example:

```
@echo off
echo CLIENT CONNECTED. Say Hello. 
:ChatBot 
set /p chat=You: 
if /i "%chat%"=="hello" echo User: Hello.. Anything you need while I can talk? These chats are on a timer.
if /i "%chat%"=="who are you?" echo User: My name is stacy. Im a Help assistant here at USFIB. 
if /i "%chat%"=="exit" goto :eof
goto ChatBot
```

Also, I put CLIENT CONNECTED above your goto label.